# I cannot remove a subdocment in mongo Db?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to delete a subdocument from my users collection in Mongo Db, my best attempt to remove the subdocument is the the route below. However is does not work. I have been able to $unset the entire Favorite Movies array but I only want to delete one Item by its _id within the Favorite Movies Sub-Document. What am I doing Wrong.

// My Route That is supposed to Delete a Subdocument:

```
app.put('/Favorites/:UserName/delete/:_id',passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    users.findOneAndUpdate({ UserName: req.params.UserName })
      .then((user) => {
          
        if (!user) {
          res.status(400).send('ID: ' + req.params._id + ' was not found!!');
        } else {
          user.updateOne(
            {UserName: req.params.UserName},
            {
              $pull: {
                "FavoriteMovies": {
                
                  "ObjectId": req.params._id
                }
              }
            
            })
          
          res.status(200).send('ID: ' + req.params._id + ' was deleted!');
          
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
      });
  });
```

//Mongoose Model Schema for User in which the Subdocuemnt I want to delete is in Favorite Movies:

```
  let usersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {type: Object},
    UserName: {type: String, required: true},
    Password: {type: String, required: true},
    Email: {type: String, required: true},
    Birthday: Date,
    FavoriteMovies:{type: Object},
    ImagePath: String
  });
```

The User Object with Favorite Movies Subdocument in Postman- Raw:

```
[
    {
        "_id": 1650119097711,
        "UserName": "robbies",
        "Password": "$2b$10$UZmRBLZF0UGWrB1OrZVI2ePc7N1ae5sSZj0RlSU8WyRIRsfdE.yYW",
        "Email": "rob@gmail.com",
        "Birthday": "1988-05-05T00:00:00.000Z",
        "FavoriteMovies": [
            {
                "ObjectId": 2009,
                "Title": "The NoteBook",
                "Genre": "Romance"
            },
            {
                "ObjectId": 2001,
                "Title": "Hacksaw Ridge",
                "Genre": "Action"
            }
        ],
        "ImagePath": null,
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: Is `FavoriteMovies` an `Object`, or an array of `Object`?

Comment: That is a Good Question to be honest I am very green at all this however excuse my ignorance but Favorite Movies Is an array of Objects.

Comment: Favorite Movies is stores a objects for  a users favorites section such as this object. I am trying to Remove specifically one of many objects in this array by the _id        Example:   {_id: 2009, Title: "Hacksaw Ridge", Genre: "Action"}

Comment: So, is the shown `usersSchema` correct with `FavoriteMovies:{type: Object}`?

Comment: Sorry, my `mongoose`/javascript knowledge is very limited, but is `user.updateOne` correct?  And in the `"$pull"`, do you want `"ObjectId"` or `"_id"`?

Comment: I will go over that and see But It was definitely one of my Questions. I have been curious if I need to make this update through Mongoose as well in the Schema as in: 
 mongoose.model.UpdateOne()                    However my knowledge of Mongoose is limited as well.

Comment: I am Trying to Get the "ObjectId" I should remove the _id: I believe...

Comment: Perhaps if you show an example `FavoriteMovies` array, it would help to uderstand.

Comment: I update the Post and added the User object with the favorite movies Subdocment that I am trying to pull.

Comment: Your [basic MongoDB update](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EDytNMLfIVb "Link to mongoplayground example -->") looks OK to me and I'm pretty sure this is just a `mongoose` syntax/usage issue.  I'm not familiar with `mongoose` and I added the tag so hopefully a "mongooser" will respond.